# MIDI on Python / PyGame, Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, pygame, midi

Trying to get a MIDI interface to work with pygame on Ubuntu 12.04. I know the keyboard works because it can control vkeybd and works with PyGame on OSX, so the issue with with MIDI in python.

```
$ python -m pygame.examples.midi --list

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pygame/examples/midi.py", line 820, in <module>
    print_device_info()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pygame/examples/midi.py", line 25, in     print_device_info
    pygame.midi.init()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pygame/midi.py", line 71, in init
    import pygame.pypm
ImportError: /usr/lib/libportmidi.so.0: undefined symbol: snd_seq_event_input_pending
```

python-pygame installed through the package manager, as is python-pm.

Any ideas? :)

Comment: Run `ldd /usr/lib/libportmidi.so.0`.  Does it show any missing libraries?

Comment: `ldd /usr/lib/libportmidi.so.0`
`linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffdabff000)`
`libporttime.so.0 => /usr/lib/libporttime.so.0 (0x00007ff35ac2f000)`
`libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007ff35a870000)`
`libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007ff35a652000)`
`/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007ff35b05e000)`

Comment: What should I be looking for?

Comment: An undefined symbol such as this may sometimes indicate a missing library.  It appears all of the required libraries are in place so this isn't your issue.  On my system, the `snd_seq_event_input_pending` function exists in the `/usr/lib/libasound.so.2` file which I don't see in your `ldd` list.  Is `libasound2` package installed?

Comment: libasound and libasound2-dev are both installed. Hmmm.

Comment: Just to confirm that updating Ubuntu 12.04 (64bit) now installs libportmidi 1.12.04.2 and fixes this problem.

Answer (score 4):

Although this won't exactly answer your question, it may help you debug the problem yourself.

The error is this :

```
ImportError: /usr/lib/libportmidi.so.0: undefined symbol: snd_seq_event_input_pending
```

The `undefined symbol` is a failure of the dynamic linker to find the code required for the `snd_seq_event_input_pending` function.

On an example 32 bit Oneiric system we can do this to look at some symbols of `libportmidi.so.0`.

```
nm -DC /usr/lib/libportmidi.so.0 | grep snd_seq_event_input_pending

U snd_seq_event_input_pending
```

This tells us that the `libportmidi` library requires the code for `snd_seq_event_input_pending` but the symbol is undefined.  So for `libportmidi` to function it must also load an additional library which contains this function.

On Oneiric I've found that this symbol is defined in `libasound2.so.2`.

```
nm -DC /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libasound.so.2 | grep snd_seq_event_input_pending

000a0fa0 T snd_seq_event_input_pending
```

The `T` indicates that the function exists and is in the text (code) segment.

Usually, linking of associated libraries occurs automatically as `libasound.so.2` should be referenced by `libportmidi`.  On the same system.

```
ldd /usr/lib/libportmidi.so.0

....
libasound.so.2 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libasound.so.2 (0x00e35000)
```

which shows that `libmidi` depends on `libasound`.  In the `ldd` output list in your comments there is no reference to `libasound`, and so it won't try to automatically dynamically link `libasound.so.2` when it is loaded, resulting in your error.

There's a few reasons why there may be an error:

- The way linking from `libportmidi` may have change from Oneiric to Precise.  eg `libportmidi` may attempt to find its own dependencies for `libasound`. (Unlikely).
- There is a bug in packaging of `libportmidi` where it doesn't reference `libasound.so.2` as it should.  This may be platform specific (eg only an error on 64 bit systems).

I'd suggest that you try to find out the library on your system that contains the `snd_seq_event_input_pending` function and then work backwards to try and determine why it has not been linked with `libportmidi`.

The following bash command will help you find the libaries implementing `snd_seq_event_input_pending`.  If you don't find anything, there's a problem with the libraries installed on your machine.

```
find /lib /usr/lib -name "lib*.so.*" | while read f; do
    if nm -DC "$f" | grep -q 'T snd_seq_event_input_pending'; then
        echo "$f"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Still investigating this, this is an awesome, awesome start though. I think this will give me what I need, I'll check back in and reward bounty once I file the proper bug in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

I have exactly the same problem (on Ubuntu 12.04.1), using e.g. the MIDI playback tool in Frescobaldi (which is a Python application). This used to work fine, but doesn't anymore.

This is quite obviously a miscompiled portmidi package which was pushed out on on 2013-01-25, see https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/portmidi/1:200-0ubuntu1.12.04.1. Downgrading to the previous 1:200-0ubuntu1 package solved the issue for me.

I guess that the proper course of action would be to file a bug report against the 1:200-0ubuntu1.12.04.1 version on Launchpad at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/portmidi/+bugs. If it doesn't get fixed, we might also ask falkTX if he would be willing to provide a working package in his KXStudio PPAs instead.

Just for the record, here's what ldd gives for the 1:200-0ubuntu1 libportmidi on my system:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffe9bff000)
libasound.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasound.so.2 (0x00007f26264cb000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f26262ae000)
libporttime.so.0 => /usr/lib/libporttime.so.0 (0x00007f26260ab000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f2625cec000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f26259f0000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f26257eb000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f26255e3000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f26269f4000)
```

And the broken 1:200-0ubuntu1.12.04.1 version:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff9e3ff000)
libporttime.so.0 => /usr/lib/libporttime.so.0 (0x00007fb84ac71000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fb84a8b2000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fb84a694000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fb84b0af000)
```

So any application which doesn't happen to link in libasound2 by itself will be hosed. Specifically, that seems to be the case for the Python portmidi module. (This kind of error is also aggravated by the fact that, at least from Ubuntu 12.04 onwards, gcc uses the --as-needed linker flag by default. I bet that there are still quite a few packages in the Ubuntu repos which are broken because of that.)

Comment: I've filed a bug report at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/portmidi/+bug/1110326 now. If everyone affected by the bug does an "affects me too" there, it might even get noticed. :)

Comment: Found and fixed the bug, please see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/portmidi/+bug/1110326. For the time being, I've uploaded a fixed package at Launchpad at https://launchpad.net/~dr-graef/+archive/test (please give it some time, the 64 bit package is still waiting to build at the time of this writing).

Answer (score 1):

If you want fix it now you can checkout the latest version of [portmidi](http://portmedia.sourceforge.net/portmidi/) and build the library as follows (assuming you've checked out or unpacked portmidi into a dir called portmidi):

```
cd portmidi
make -f pm_linux/Makefile
```

The default install doesn't build a dynamic version of library so you need to build one like this:

```
gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,libportmidi.so.0 -o  pm_linux/libportmidi.so.0 pm_common/pmutil.o pm_linux/pmlinuxalsa.o pm_linux/pmlinux.o pm_common/portmidi.o -lasound
```

Then you can make a copy of the old library (just in case), and then copy this new one in its place:

```
sudo cp /usr/lib/libportmidi.so.0 /usr/lib/libportmidi.so.0.orig
sudo cp pm_linux/libportmidi.so.0 /usr/lib/libportmidi.so.0
```

Your apps should now work...